# Android TextView text won't center

Tags: android, layout, textview

I am trying to make a PIN entry activity, but one little thing is not quite working for me. I can't get the text to center in the TextView's at the top of the screenshot here:

[image: Pin Screenshot]

The way it will work is when the user is entering a PIN, I will place a star in each TextView for visible feedback. The problem is, I want the star to be centered. I have tried layout_gravity="center", but it doesn't make a difference. Here's my current layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <TextView 
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:id="@+id/textView1" 
     android:text="PIN Required" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
     android:layout_marginBottom="12sp"
     ></TextView>
     <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_marginBottom="12sp" 
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     >
         <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/text1" 
       android:layout_height="32sp" 
       android:layout_width="48sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:layout_marginRight="2sp" 
       android:layout_marginLeft="48sp" 
       android:background="#FFFFFF" 
       android:text="X" 
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       ></TextView>
         <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/text2" 
       android:layout_height="32sp" 
       android:layout_width="48sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:layout_marginRight="2sp" 
       android:layout_marginLeft="2sp" 
       android:background="#FFFFFF"
       ></TextView>
         <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/text3" 
       android:layout_height="32sp" 
       android:layout_width="48sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:layout_marginRight="2sp" 
       android:layout_marginLeft="2sp" 
       android:background="#FFFFFF"
       ></TextView>
         <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/text4" 
       android:layout_height="32sp" 
       android:layout_width="48sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:layout_marginRight="48sp" 
       android:layout_marginLeft="2sp" 
       android:background="#FFFFFF"
       ></TextView>
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_marginBottom="12sp"
     >
         <Button 
       android:text="1" 
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
       android:id="@+id/button1" 
       android:layout_height="32sp" 
       android:layout_width="64sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:editable="false" 
       android:layout_marginRight="2sp" 
       android:layout_marginLeft="48sp" 
       android:background="@drawable/action_background_gradient" 
       android:onClick="ButtonClicked"
       ></Button>
         <Button 
       android:text="2" 
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
       android:id="@+id/button2" 
       android:layout_height="32sp" 
       android:layout_width="64sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:editable="false" 
       android:layout_marginRight="2sp" 
       android:layout_marginLeft="2sp" 
       android:background="@drawable/action_background_gradient" 
       android:onClick="ButtonClicked"
       ></Button>
         <Button 
       android:text="3" 
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
       android:id="@+id/button3" 
       android:layout_height="32sp" 
       android:layout_width="64sp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:editable="false" 
       android:layout_marginRight="48sp" 
       android:layout_marginLeft="2sp" 
       android:background="@drawable/action_background_gradient" 
       android:onClick="ButtonClicked"
       ></Button>
     </LinearLayout>

     <!--... and so on for the rest of the buttons ... -->
 </LinearLayout>
```

I've got that android:text="X" in there for the first textview just so I can see if it is working. When I am done tweaking the layout, that will go away.
What simple thing am I missing?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

use `android:gravity="center"`

although I'm not seeing any EditText element in your code. You sure you posted the right code?

Comment: That's because I am a knucklehead and I meant to say TextView. Working on two things at once. But I do have the gravity="center" in there and it isn't working.

Comment: Doh! I have layout_gravity, rather than just gravity. Sigh... Thanks!

Comment: Aaah! How many times will I make this same mistake!! I should tattoo layout_^H^H^H^H^H^H^Hgravity on my forehead.

Answer (score 15):

```
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/text1" 
   android:layout_height="32sp" 
   android:layout_width="48sp" 
   android:layout_weight="1" 
   android:layout_marginRight="2sp" 
   android:layout_marginLeft="48sp" 
   android:background="#FFFFFF" 
   android:text="X" 
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:gravity="center"
/>
```

`android:layout_gravity="center"` relates to this View's position in it's parent.
`android:gravity="center"` relates to where this View's contents are positioned.

Comment: For my particular activity, setting `android:gravity` alone to `center` did not resolve the problem, I also needed to set `android:layout_gravity` to `center` +1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of android:layout_gravity in text view use `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

Answer (score 0):

To centre the text, use `android:gravity` on the TextView, not layout_gravity:

```
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/text1" 
   android:layout_height="32sp" 
   android:layout_width="48sp" 
   android:layout_weight="1" 
   android:layout_marginRight="2sp" 
   android:layout_marginLeft="48sp" 
   android:background="#FFFFFF" 
   android:text="X" 
   android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done programmatically as well, of-course:

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```