# How to center a TextView on the parent ImageView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've tried several ways of doing this and failed each time.

What I want to acomplish is centering TextView (horizontally and vertically) on ImageView, but instead command android:layout_centerInParent="true" results in vertical and horizontal centering on the whole area, not on ImageView. Please help me with attaching parent to TextView or other way of solving this.

Here is my xml code:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="Your Height BG"
    android:src="@drawable/textareabg" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView00"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"

    android:text="Your Height"
    android:textColor="#d88b6d"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: id use `RelativeLayout` as parent and set its background as to what the `ImageView` has but you can try other ways around if you dont like this

Comment: is your imageview of fixed height and width ?

Answer (score 2):

It can be easily acheived using `ConstraintLayout`. Android recently introduced `ConstraintLayout`. It allows us to lay out child views using ‘constraints’ to define position based relationships between different views found in our layout. It is similar to `RelativeLayout`, but much more powerful than it because, ConstraintLayout reduces View Hierarchy to a greater extent. Now getting back to your question, Here is the sample xml code which does the work for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image"
       android:layout_width="200dp"
       android:layout_height="200dp"
       android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1"/>

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Image"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/image"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/image"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output View on Device

[image: device_output]

You can position the TextView anywhere on the ImageView using **app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias** and **app:layout_constraintVertical_bias**. By default these values will be set to **0.5**. So, it will be center aligned by default , if we don't specify any values.

> When you add a constraint to both sides of a view (and the view size
>   for the same dimension is either "fixed" or "wrap content"), the view
>   becomes centered between the two anchor points by default.

**Note:** Bias attribute only works if you specify the constraints for the boundaries (e.g. top and bottom for vertical bias, left and right for horizontal bias)

More about ConstraintLayout

[ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

[Sample Project](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)

[Blog on ConstraintLayout](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1#.56hsitlhg)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would help you with your question

[Android TextView text won't center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014819/android-textview-text-wont-center)

A person here mentions using `android:gravity="center"`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick for me. Please keep in mind I'm new to this and it might be something I'm doing wrong that I didn't state here, so would be great if you could guide me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="170dp"
      android:layout_height="46dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:contentDescription="Your Height BG"
      android:src="@drawable/textareabg" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView00"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:text="Your Height"
      android:textColor="#d88b6d"
      android:textSize="20sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="Your Height BG" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView00"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:text="Your Height"
     android:textColor="#d88b6d"
     android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use FrameLayout.The doc says:

FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.

**Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top.** The size of the FrameLayout is the size of its largest child (plus padding), visible or not (if the FrameLayout's parent permits). Views that are GONE are used for sizing only if setConsiderGoneChildrenWhenMeasuring() is set to true.

So you need something like following psuedo layout code:

```
<FrameLayout>
   <ImageView gravity="center">
   <TextView gravity="center">
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more relative layout under your layout like this :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Check for width and height you want. Eg. If you want specific height and width for image, change height and width of this relative layout.

Thats it...